# Как правильно настроить location в nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Вопрос заключается в следующем:

Есть основной домен `example.com`

Его `nginx` настройка:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key.pem;

    location / {
        root /var/www/example.com/app;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }

    location /buy {
        alias /var/www/some_other_folder/public/;
    }

}
```

При запросе https://example.com/ - отображается что и должно
При запросе https://example.com/buy - отображается html, тоже который нужен только стили пытается вытянуть из https://example.com/, что, в принципе, нормально.

Вопрос - как в конфиге прописать, чтобы если мы в директории `/buy`, то и статичные файлы брать оттуда?

Comment: а в src статики писать `/buy/images/image.jpg` не прокатывает?

Comment: нет, к сожалению

Comment: в другой папке просто странички или фреймворковое приложение с общей точкой входа и роутером?

Comment: фреймворк там лежит

Comment: *если мы в директории /buy* — об этом ведь знает только код, генерирующий html. вот в него и вносите изменения, чтобы html выглядел так, как вам надо.

Comment: apache с помощью `mod_rewrite` что -то подобное позволяет сделать, с помощью nginx такое сделать не получится?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте директиву [root](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) вместо [alias](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

Comment: пробовал - то, что сейчас отображается, тоже перестает отображаться и кидает 404